# How come this code is not faster with Numba?

Tags: python, numba

Why is this monte carlo simulation not faster with numba jit? Removing `@jit` makes it run a bit faster. However, I thought these loops where what numba was good at...

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

T = 1000
ALPHA = 0.11
BETA = 0.22
GAMMA = 0.33

@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def sim(n):
  mu = np.array([0.0, 0.1]).reshape(2,1)
  rho = 0.1
  sigma = np.array([[1, rho*4],[rho*4, 4^2]])
  A = np.linalg.cholesky(sigma)

  out = np.empty((n, 2))
  for i in range(n):
    # (a)
    u = np.random.randn(T)

    # X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, sigma, T)
    X = mu + A @ np.random.randn(2,T)
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((T, 1)), X.T), axis=1)

    y = X @ np.array([ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA]) + u

    # (b)
    thetahat = np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @ y)

    Xf = X[:,:2].copy()
    thetatilde = np.linalg.solve(Xf.T @ Xf, Xf.T @ y)

    out[i,:] = (thetahat[1], thetatilde[1])

  return out

n = 10**5
s = sim(n)
print(s)
```

Comment: You are mostly using compiled functions in the loop. Not much to `jit` there.  `numba` can improve the speed if you have to loop over a `numpy` array or a `python` collection. The jitted function runs ~1.04x faster on my machine but that's in the noise.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny is right, Numba generally does not make a significant improvement over idiomatic NumPy. It is however very useful for compiling fast custom ufuncs (which NumPy can't do) and optimizing unidiomatic loops. It doesn't simply "speed up" a loop, though, it depends on if your code benefits from type inference.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#how-to-measure-the-performance-of-numba) states:

> First, recall that Numba has to compile your function for the argument types given before it executes the machine code version of your function, this takes time. However, once the compilation has taken place Numba caches the machine code version of your function for the particular types of arguments presented. If it is called again the with same types, it can reuse the cached version instead of having to compile again.

> A really common mistake when measuring performance is to not account for the above behaviour and to time code once with a simple timer that includes the time taken to compile your function in the execution time.

simply: in the first execution (in your case, the only one) numba compiles it to machine code. It takes time. If you run it once again, then you will see the difference.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import time

T = 1000
ALPHA = 0.11
BETA = 0.22
GAMMA = 0.33

@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def sim(n):
  mu = np.array([0.0, 0.1]).reshape(2,1)
  rho = 0.1
  sigma = np.array([[1, rho*4],[rho*4, 4^2]])
  A = np.linalg.cholesky(sigma)

  out = np.empty((n, 2))
  for i in range(n):
    # (a)
    u = np.random.randn(T)

    # X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, sigma, T)
    X = mu + A @ np.random.randn(2,T)
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((T, 1)), X.T), axis=1)

    y = X @ np.array([ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA]) + u

    # (b)
    thetahat = np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @ y)

    Xf = X[:,:2].copy()
    thetatilde = np.linalg.solve(Xf.T @ Xf, Xf.T @ y)

    out[i,:] = (thetahat[1], thetatilde[1])

  return out

n = 10**2
start = time.time()
sim(n)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))

s = sim(n)
start = time.time()
sim(n)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
print(s)
```

Here I ran the simulation twice. The first run took 5 seconds, but the second run took only 0.01 seconds. Numba improved indeed.

Numba is useful when you have a function you using multiple times. For a single execution, numba has no use.

Comment: I couldn't get any noticeable speed improvements with a warmed up jitted function.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny running with `n=10^4` multiple times, with numba it takes on average 1.5 seconds and without numba it takes 2.5 seconds on average. In this calculations I didn't include the first execution when the function compiles.

Comment: My results are comparable to OPs and with your `numba` benchmark. I wonder why your pure numpy function is much slower. Which BLAS backend do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use the "Eager compilation" and the document can be found at https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, float64, uint32

T = 1000
ALPHA = 0.11
BETA = 0.22
GAMMA = 0.33

# using the eager compilation
@jit(float64[:, :](uint32))
def sim(n):
  # the code below is not changed at all
  mu = np.array([0.0, 0.1]).reshape(2,1)
  rho = 0.1
  sigma = np.array([[1, rho*4],[rho*4, 4^2]])
  A = np.linalg.cholesky(sigma)

  out = np.empty((n, 2))
  for i in range(n):
    # (a)
    u = np.random.randn(T)

    # X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, sigma, T)
    X = mu + A @ np.random.randn(2,T)
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((T, 1)), X.T), axis=1)

    y = X @ np.array([ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA]) + u

    # (b)
    thetahat = np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @ y)

    Xf = X[:,:2].copy()
    thetatilde = np.linalg.solve(Xf.T @ Xf, Xf.T @ y)

    out[i,:] = (thetahat[1], thetatilde[1])

  return out

n = 10**5
# calculate the elapsed time
start = time.time()
s = sim(n)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
print(s)
```

On my computer, the code above using the eager compilation is about 7s faster.